# Телеграм бот, создающий телеграм бота с определёнными функциями

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как возможно написать телеграм бота, создающего другого тг бота на основе токена, который пользователь пошлёт. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ну для начала вы должны определиться с **ограничениями функционала** *(подключение сторонних библиотек и т.п.)*.
2. Также нужно будет разработать *(неважно, на каком языке)* программу, которая будет **генерировать код нового бота по заданному шаблону** и **запускать сгенерированный код на исполнение** (возможно, нужно будет использовать какой-нибудь `Docker` или любой другой виртуальный контейнер для каждого нового бота).
3. Далее вам нужен будет **сервер** *(не важно, виртуальный или обычный)*, на котором должна будет **работать написанная вами программа из пункта 2**, принимающая данные, которые пошлет пользователь (токен, настройки функционала).

---

**Примечание.** Если это в целях учебного проекта, то хватит и одного не очень мощного сервера. **Но если**, вы хотите сделать из этого что-то серьезное, то одного сервера не хватит и нужно будет распределять нагрузку между несколькими серверами.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Допустим, написан весь функционал, но каким образом воможно передать токен от бота-бати?

Comment: @Максим не понимаю вашего вопроса, что именно вам непонятно в передаче данных?

Comment: @Максим И если ответ вам помог нужно отметить его как правильный.

Comment: Я понимаю,как написать программку,генерирующую код по шаблону. Понимаю,как написать бота,принимающего токен от пользователя. Но не могу понять,как отправить токен от бота генерирующему коду. В моей голове это две независимые программы,ибо видимо знаний не хватает) в общем, подскажите,пожалуйста, что мне изучить,чтоб понять эту тему)

Comment: @Максим пересылка данных осуществляется с помощью протоколов `tcp` или `udp`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!